# How to generate a probability density function and expectation in r?

Tags: r, statistics

The task:

> Eric the fly has a friend, Ernie. Assume that the two flies sit at independent locations, uniformly distributed on the globe’s surface. Let D denote the Euclidean distance between Eric and Ernie (i.e., on a straight line through the interior of the globe).
>
> Make a conjecture about the probability density function of D and give an
> estimate of its expected value, E(D).

So far I have made a function to generate two points on the globe's surface, but I am unsure what to do next:

```
sample3d <- function(2)
  {
  df <- data.frame()
  while(n > 0){
    x <- runif(1,-1,1)
    y <- runif(1,-1,1)
    z <- runif(1,-1,1)
    r <- x^2 + y^2 + z^2
    if (r < 1){
      u <- sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)
      vector = data.frame(x = x/u,y = y/u, z = z/u)
      df <- rbind(vector,df)
      n = n- 1
    }
  }
  df
}
E <- sample3d(2)
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! I formatted your question so that the code is something that is easier for users to copy and paste. When you post questions, don't just copy and paste from your console. The prompt (`>`)  and the line continuation characters (`+`) shouldn't be included in the codeblock. Hope that helps!

Comment: In general terms, you'd want to either compute the distance for all possible pairs of points on the surface and histogram the results, or take N measurements using two randomly-distributed points on the surface for large N and histogram that. That all relies on your points being spread uniformly over the surface though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting problem. I'll outline a computational approach; I'll leave the math up to you.

1. First we fix a random seed for reproducibility.

   ```
   set.seed(2018);
   ```
2. We sample `10^4` points from the unit sphere surface.

   ```
   sample3d <- function(n = 100) {
     df <- data.frame();
     while(n > 0) {
       x <- runif(1,-1,1)
       y <- runif(1,-1,1)
       z <- runif(1,-1,1)
       r <- x^2 + y^2 + z^2
       if (r < 1) {
         u <- sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)
         vector = data.frame(x = x/u,y = y/u, z = z/u)
         df <- rbind(vector,df)
         n = n- 1
       }
     }
     df
   }
   df <- sample3d(10^4);
   ```

   Note that `sample3d` is not very efficient, but that's a different issue.
3. We now randomly sample 2 points from `df`, calculate the Euclidean distance between those two points (using `dist`), and repeat this procedure `N = 10^4` times.

   ```
   # Sample 2 points randomly from df, repeat N times
   N <- 10^4;
   dist <- replicate(N, dist(df[sample(1:nrow(df), 2), ]));
   ```

   As pointed out by @JosephWood, the number `N = 10^4` is somewhat arbitrary. We are using a [bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) to derive the empirical distribution. For `N -> infinity` one can show that the empirical bootstrap distribution is the same as the (unknown) population distribution (Bootstrap theorem). The error term between empirical and population distribution is of the order `1/sqrt(N)`, so `N = 10^4` should lead to an error around 1%.
4. We can plot the resulting probability distribution as a histogram:

   ```
   # Let's plot the distribution
   ggplot(data.frame(x = dist), aes(x)) + geom_histogram(bins = 50);
   ```

[image]

4. Finally, we can get empirical estimates for the mean and median.

   ```
   # Mean
   mean(dist);
   #[1] 1.333021

   # Median
   median(dist);
   #[1] 1.41602
   ```

   These values are close to the theoretical values:

   ```
   mean.th = 4/3
   median.th = sqrt(2)
   ```

Comment: Nice work as always. Just throwing it out there, I think this answer would be better if you showed why you chose `10^4` arbitrarily. I'm thinking the _Law of Large Numbers_ could be a nice insertion. Again nice work!

Comment: Thanks @JosephWood, also for the comment and reference to the LoLN! I've made an edit to elaborate a bit more on the `N=10^4` in the bootstrap part.

Comment: You're very welcome @Ella; this is a nice & interesting problem. BTW, if you want to improve your code, [Marsaglia published a nice paper in 1972](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177692644), where he discusses/summarises 4 different (and probably more efficient) methods for sampling from the unit sphere surface (thanks to @42- for pointing this out in a different post). Might be worth a read.